# What is the difference between ad hoc distribution and app store distribution in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, ad-hoc-distribution

I am new in iPhone development. I have a little idea about app_store distribution. My questions are

1. what is the need for ad hoc distribution in ios application distribution?

2)Is any other license needed for ad hoc distribution from Apple?

if anybody knows, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Ad-Hoc Distribution:**
Distribution builds of an app, which can be installed on 100 devices designated by the developer on his provisioning portal. The distribution mechanism can be websites, mails or OTA. These type of builds are generally for beta testing or demos.

**App-store Distribution:**
Distribution builds that are intended for general public(for sale). The distribution mechanism is App store only.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have one question ,Is the ad hoc distribution possible for give the application to client with out source code.

Comment: That's what they are for. Send the build and your client would be able to run the app without the code. However you'd have to add his device to your provisioning portal.

Comment: Now for new test flight app in the iTunes connect, Should we use app distribution file or ad hoc distribution file for external beta testing

Comment: What does OTA stand for in this context?

Comment: @Dima Over The Air installation.

Answer (score 9):

Ad Hoc distribution allows you to share your application with up to 100 iPhone, iPad or iPod touch users, and to distribute your application through email or by posting it to a web site or server.

**App Store provisioning profiles do not allow for a distribution built application to be installed on an Apple device. To install your distribution ready application on a device, you must create an Ad Hoc provisioning profile.**

App Store distribution allows you to post your application in Apple Store.